# icCube - MDX - Putting The Two Dates Of The DateRangePicker ( Start Date , End Date ) In the PieChart Columns

Tags: datepicker, mdx, iccube, iccube-reporting

When I apply a filter by (Start date, End date ) using DateRangePicker on the PieChart, I need to export it to Excel , so it's important to export including those two dates.
I hope that any one help me to find a solution for this problem. Txs, Marwen

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want, can you rephrase  and explain in more detail ?

Comment: I want to export the PieChart on Excel, but the Excal file must contain the two dates (Start date , End date) of the datePicker.